# Move Apache's /var/www/html to another mount-point/disk?

Tags: apache2, symbolic-link, html, www

I've got a vm set up with Apache and mysql and it works so far:

[image]

but it only has 16gb, just for Ubuntu, Apache and Mysql. But I've also got a data disk:

[image]

I've done the steps to change the document-root: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-an-apache-web-root-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

However, when I try to access the url, I get

[image]

Why? I checked, and they're both the same owner/permissions:

[image]
[image]

I haven't the foggiest how to do it with symlinks, which was suggested to me.

Comment: If you are sure you have copied the whole `html` directory to `disc1`, remove it from the root partition: `sudo rm -r /var/www/html` and create a symlink: `sudo ln -s /net/vmits0356/disk1/html /var/www/html`. Don't run everything as root, that is bad practice.

Comment: I did your steps, still getting 403 forbidden

Comment: That will be because the target directory is owned by `root` and not by the web server user, which will be `www-data` if you are running Apache2. Do `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html`.

Comment: Nope, still the same, 403 Forbidden, with www-data as owner. Another problem, the symlink doesn't seem to be working: https://i.imgur.com/ErluLLm.png , https://i.imgur.com/DAILRjf.png !

Comment: Omg....disc not disk...problem solved!